# Working with animation or Linear Layout

Tags: android, eclipse

when I click on button then an animation goes to left to right and right to left only for menu section layout and according to this animation the width of other layout (head of family should be expand or collapse..

my problem is that the animation for menu layout is working properly but the width of other layout  not to collapse or expand simultaneously ,how can i do this.

my code is this

```
 if(flagmenu)
{
//menu layout set animation
                  lpmenu.startAnimation(animationFallout);           
                  Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          try {
                              Thread.sleep(2500);
                                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                  public void run() {
                                      lpmenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
                                });
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }   
                        }
                    });
                    t.start();
                //  lpmenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  flagmenu = false;
                 }
               else
                 {
                  lpmenu.startAnimation(animationFalling);
                  lpmenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  flagmenu = true;
                 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Use this animation code here v is view group mean layout interpolatedTime of animation work fine for me  . if code for collapse if u want expend then use + sine  
        Animation a = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                    Transformation t) {
                if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    v.getLayoutParams().width= initialwidth
                            - (int) (initialwidth * interpolatedTime);
// replace - to + for expend 
                    v.requestLayout();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest you to use [ObjectAnimators](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) to achieve this instead of Animations, since Animation does not actually change the View's position. Then, in order to perform simultaneous animations with Animators you may use [AnimatorSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html) class (playTogether method). If you need to support old Android versions there is a [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library which backports Animators. Another way (without animators) is to use [AnimationSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html) (again you should add Animations for each view you want to move) class and implement [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) changing the Layoutparams of your views (in order to update layout)

Comment: @Er Swati Agrawal, so was my answer helpful, or maybe it should be expanded?